# Read CSV and write two differents xml files - best practices

Tags: java, xml, delegates, spring-batch, writer

I have a batch that reads a .csv file and maps its data into a POJO.
I need to write two XML files as output. Currently, to write these two files, I generated classes via XJC from their XSD.

I am writing from a FlatFileItemWriter (written in a text file which is useless) via a delegator. It is in this delegator that I write my two XML files. The batch works fine, I produce both XML files as output, no problem. However, I'm not satisfied because I'm producing a useless empty .txt file and I'm using a FlatFileItemWriter, that's not the way to do it.

```java
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<MetaCsv> csvWriter(MetaAgregator aggregator) {
    FlatFileItemWriter<MetaCsv> flatFileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    String outFilePath = "resources/data/esopetosae/output/out.txt";
    flatFileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(outFilePath));
    flatFileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(aggregator);
    flatFileItemWriter.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
    flatFileItemWriter.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
    return flatFileItemWriter;
}
```

Aggregator:

```java
@Bean
public MetaAgregator aggregator() {
    return new MetaAgregator ();
}
```

How can I make my Writer manage the writing of the two different XML files (different rootXML, different structure and data) while keeping the aggregator? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The `FlatFileItemWriter` is designed to write flat files, not XML files.

In your case, you can use a `CompositeItemWriter` with two `StaxEventItemWriter`s as delegates to generate two XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

Merci pour le retour.

Je vais essayer avec CompositeItemWriter et deux StaxEventItemWriter. Mais pourrais je utiliser les classes Java générées avec Xjc qui me permettent d'écrire les XmL actuellement ?

Cdt,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).